# How to require a checkbox to be checked at client side before form gets submitted to server in MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a Terms and Condition checkbox on my signup page.
I want to make it required like my few other fields on the form before posting to server.
This validation must be done at client side.

Anyone knows how to do it properly?

I am using MVC 3, jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "terms and condition")]
[Display(Name = "terms")]
public bool Terms { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Terms, new { @class = "cb" }) Terms & Condition
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn">Signup</button>
```

Also,
   Is it possible to call/trap some JS function when the submit button is clicked?
   That way I can easily use jquery to do validation and then submit?

Thanks for reading

Comment: the event that you need is `onSubmit`

Comment: How do I finally submit from the function I call in onSubmit? Do I need to set something to true which will then submit to server to complete the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom validation attribute:

```
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value is bool && (bool)value)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return new ValidationResult(String.Format(ErrorMessageString, validationContext.DisplayName));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "shouldbetrue"
        };

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

which would be used to decorate your model:

```
[MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "terms and condition")]
[Display(Name = "terms")]
public bool Terms { get; set; }
```

and finally in the view register it:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Terms, new { @class = "cb" }) 
    <text>Terms &amp; Condition</text>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Terms)

    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn">Signup</button>
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>           
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>           

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('shouldbetruemethod', function (value, element) {
        return $(element).is(':checked');
    }, '');

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('shouldbetrue', 'shouldbetruemethod');
</script>
```

Comment: Darin, Is there a sequence dependency of the js code to register it? Do I need to call it inside $(document).ready(function () {})?

Comment: @Projapati, I usually put all my script registrations at the end, just before the closing `</body>` and don't use document.ready. I've updated my answer to provide a more precise example of how the view might look like. The only thing you could do is to use a section called scripts in the layout and override this section in the view in order to include the scripts just at the end of the document.

Comment: That's the name you will be assigned in the javascript. `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('shouldbetrue' ... `

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing the validation part?

```
@Html.ValidationFor(m => m.Terms)
```

---

To hook up the submit is just hooking up, either the button click, or the form submit:

```
$(".btn").bind("click", function() {
    // Button was clicked, do stuff here
    return true; // so it can process the form submit
});
```

and

```
$("form").bind("submit", function() {
    // Form was submitted, do stuff here
    return true; // so it can process the form submit to the server (return false if you dont want to submit)
});
```

you can always use:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { @id = "myForm" }, FormMethod.Post, null)) {
...
}
```

and hook up with the Selector Id

```
$("#myForm").bind("submit", function() { ... });
```

---

To use a `CheckBox` with the attribute `Required`, you need to do a custom validation just copy/paste [Darin's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422190/how-to-require-a-checkbox-to-be-checked-at-client-side-before-form-gets-submitted/6422304#6422304), to understand why the `[Required]` doesn't work out of the box you need to understand the output HTML

required validation in jQuery Validation means that a value is needed, like:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="myTextbox" />
```

but in case of a checkbox, a value is always there

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="myChackbox" checked="checked" />
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="myChackbox" />
```

so the `Required` is always true.

you just need to hook up a custom event, follow Darin's code and you set to go.

Comment: Is this only for checkbox or for all fields?

Comment: it should be there for all fields, or it will not write the validation HTML that is needed. I don't use it as I don't want to use jQuery validation.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I will try this.

Comment: updated so you understand what the code is doing upon a `checkbox`

Comment: I agree. If the checkbox is NOT checked, it still has a value value of false. Of the 2 approach custom valition attribute vs custom js hook, which is one recommended? I will have checkboxes in other views which would be required.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop `Terms` from your model and simply add a checkbox to the page like so:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
...
<label>
    I agree to the terms & condition
    <input id="terms" type="checkbox" />
</label>
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn">Signup</button>
}
```

and attach an event handler to the change event to toggle your submit button.

```
$('#terms').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).siblings('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: But David, If the checkbox is readonly, how can it toggle the submit button? Or you meant to disable the submit btn?

Comment: This has slight usability issue. User might wonder why the clicking of the submit button not working? Otherwise OK

Comment: alternatively you could handle submit and check to see that it;s checked.